# Gaussian integral of analytical function

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-theory

I would like to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2`\sigma^2}} \mathrm dx$$

given that $f$ is smooth enough.

Now, if $f$ is a polynomial there is no problem as this would simply be the sum of the moments. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_and_functional_generalization) I read that for some analytical functions that satisfy some growth and "other technical" requirements, the following holds

> $$\int f(\vec{x})e^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^nA_{ij}x_ix_j\right)}\mathrm d^nx = \sqrt{\frac{(2\pi)^n}{\text{det}(A)}}\text{exp}\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n\left(A^{-1}\right)_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i }\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}\right)f(\vec{x})\Biggr\vert_{\vec{x}=0}$$

but it doesn't mention *what these requirements are.*

Also it doesn't mention anything for non-zero mean Gaussians.

> **Question:** *What are these requirements? Or, where can I find more informations? I had a look in the books available to me, but it doesn't seem to be mentioned.*

At the moment I am approximating these kind of integrals using Taylor expansions centered on the mean, as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables) , but if I can restrict myself to the aforementioned functions, I could make use of such equality.

Thank you.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is smooth enough and has a Taylor series with infinite radius you can expand $f(x)$ with a Taylor series.

Comment: I think you are looking for the [Weierstrass transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform)

Comment: You can view this as taking the expectation of a function of a normal random variable via the Law of the Unconscious Statistician.

Comment: @user137769 that was my application indeed